# Regular cast doesnot throw runtime error

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, static-cast

If we see the below code, fun function converts C's object into B's object and calls B' own function. How doesn't it give segm fault. I think this will lead to crash. 
My program is not crashed. Can any one explains why is it working fine.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
   A() {cout<<"A's Con\n"; }
   ~A() {cout<<"A's De\n"; }
};
class B :public A
{
public:
   B() {cout<<"B's Con\n"; }
   ~B() {cout<<"B's De\n"; }
   void printb(){cout<<"B print function\n";}
   void printb2(){cout<<"B print2 function\n";}
};
class C :public A
{
public:
   C() {cout<<"C's Con\n"; }
   ~C() {cout<<"C's De\n"; }
   void printc(){cout<<"C print function\n";}
};
void fun(A *ap)
{
   B *bp = (B*) ap;
   bp->printb2();
}

int main()
{
   C c;
   fun(&c);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

Comment: proper indentation and proper English would help

Comment: sry.. I did not concentrate much while writing

Comment: Hi, how do i do run time typechecking without using dynamic_cast,  I dont want to use dynamic_cast , Can I do with static_cast or any other ////

Answer (score 2):

You're invoking undefined behavior.  The first rule about undefined behavior is that *anything could happen*.  Your program might crash, or it might work successfully.  It might *appear* to work successfully and then crash hours later in an "impossible" way.  It might even send inappropriate emails to your boss or erase your hard drive.  That's certainly unlikely for a random benign error, but if your program is, say, a web browser, it could certainly be exploited to do whatever an attacker might want.

Never rely on undefined behavior.  Always fix the underling issues.  Use tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), etc. to help you catch subtle errors that don't always result in crashes.  It will make your software much more reliable in the long run.

Comment: Thanks alot. We can use static cast after checking typeid of object ( using RTTI)  Am i correct ?

Comment: Hi... Can any one suggest how to write code for the above requirement